# how to delete words which are same in two files?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two text file.

**file1.txt** has:

```
gedit
google chrome
git
vim
foo
bar
```

**file2.txt** has:

```
firefox
svn
foo
vim
```

How do I write a script that when executed (with *file1.txt* and *file2.txt* as argument) checks for duplication of text in **each line** (I mean it should process line wise), deletes the duplicated text in both the files.

So after the processing, both *file1.txt* and *file2.txt* should have following contents:

```
gedit
google chrome
git
bar
firefox
svn
```

*Notice that `foo` and `vim` has been removed from both files.*

Any guidance?

Comment: why have 2 files with the same contnents? how big are these files, can they fit into memory when both open at the same time? + [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far?

Comment: Try using a set() data structure to find duplicates. http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html

Comment: @deathApril Assume that I am reinstalling my Ubuntu. So I get a list of packages by `dpkg --get-selection` command (file1.txt) and there is another list by made by my own (file2.txt), this file contains what I remember what I have installed. After reinstalling Ubuntu I installed software by seeing file2.txt. Now the remaining contents of both the files need to be installed. Now the rest part are in my question....

Comment: Always try to think of the right datatype for each individual task. If that succeeds your way is smoothed out. The easiest way is to look out for already existing datatypes which can fit your needs (and the needs of internal functions): least trouble, best effectiveness.

Comment: does the order of content matter?

Comment: @Santosh then check out my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open('file1.txt','r+') as f1 ,open('file2.txt','r+') as f2:
    file1=set(x.strip() for x in f1 if x.strip())
    file2=set(x.strip() for x in f2 if x.strip())
    newfile=file1.symmetric_difference(file2) #symmetric difference removes those values which are present in both sets, and returns a new set.
    f2.truncate(0) #truncate the file to 0 bytes
    f1.truncate(0)
    f2.seek(0) # to push the cursor back to the starting pointing in the file.
    f1.seek(0)
    for x in newfile:
        f1.write(x+'\n')
        f2.write(x+'\n')
```

**now both files contains:**

```
svn
git
firefox
gedit
google chrome
bar
```

Comment: +1 nice touch with the symmetric difference (`file1 ^ file2`)

Comment: What does `set()` do?

Comment: @SantoshKumar set returns unique items from an iterable/iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You will save the filtered file as a third file?

Anyway, make 2 loops over each file and compare each loop index value with the other one and if they equal, delet and move respectfully. Pseudo code:

```
Def func(File a, File b):
 for i in a: 
    for j in b:
      if a[i]==b[j]:
        copy and move
      endif
     endfor
  endfor
```

Comment: No, I want the duplicated to be removed from both the file (modification in both the file).

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly, it should be easy.

```
alist = []
for i in ifile1:
    alist.append(i)

for i in ifile2:
    if i in alist:
        alist.remove(i)
    else:
        alist.append(i)

for i in alist:
    print i
```

Comment: set will be a better way to do it if you have large number of data.

Answer (score 0):

if the files are reasonably small to fit into memory, this will do the job:

```
with open("file1.txt", "r") as f1, open("file2.txt", "r") as f2:
    # create a set from the bigger file 
    result = set(x.strip() for x in f1.readlines())
    # remove duplicates or add unique values from 2nd file
    for line in f2:
        line = line.strip()
        if line in result:
            result.remove(line)
        else:
            result.add(line)
result = "\n".join(result)

# for debug, don't replace original files
with open("file1_out.txt", "w") as f1, open("file2_out.txt", "w") as f2:
    f1.write(result)
    f2.write(result)

# if not inside a function, free memory explicitly  
del result
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python 2.7+ where [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects) was introduced

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> file_1 = ['gedit','google chrome','git','vim','foo','bar']
>>> file_2 = ['firefox','svn','foo','vim']
>>> de_dup = [i for i,c in Counter(file_1+file_2).itertimes() if c == 1]
>>> de_dup
['svn', 'git', 'bar', 'gedit', 'google chrome', 'firefox']
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's start with the input file names:

```
files = ('raz.txt','dwa.txt')
```

And some helper functions. This one is a generator that reads all words from the file,

```
def read(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if len(line)>0:
                yield line.strip()
```

And this writes a sequence to the file.

```
def write(filename, lines):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

So let's create two generators - one for each input file

```
words = [read(filename) for filename in files]
```

Then, let's transform that list of generators into a list of sets

```
wordSets = map(set, words)
```

Now we have a list of 2 sets containing only the unique words from each file.

Let's create another set that contains words present in all input files, by intersecting their sets:

```
commonWords = set.intersection(*wordSets)
```

And time for the rewriting.

```
for filename in files:
```

Since we want to save to the exact same file, unfortunately we need to first read its whole contents to memory, and then write it from there. (If you wanted the output in different files, you wouldn't have to buffer the file.

Let's create a reader generator and then read all of it to memory by wrapping it with `list()`:

```
    lines = list(read(filename))
```

and then write the words back to the given file, in order, but only if they are not in commonWords

```
    write(filename, (word for word in lines if word not in commonWords))
```

---

Input:

raz.txt

```
gedit
google chrome
git
vim
foo
bar
```

dwa.txt

```
firefox
svn
foo
vim
```

Output:

raz.txt

```
gedit
google chrome
git
bar
```

dwa.txt

```
firefox
svn
```

The duplicates were removed from both.

Comment: sorry for -1, but i find this post unreadable - `# comments might help`